# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: in training dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
                                     kernel_size=3, 
                                     padding="same", 
                                     activation="relu", 
                                     input_shape=[128, 128, 1]))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, 
                                         strides=2, 
                                         padding='valid'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, 
                                      kernel_size=3, 
                                      padding="same", 
                                      activation="relu"))

classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, 
                                         strides=2, 
                                         padding='valid'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, 
                                     activation='relu'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=96, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='softmax')) # softmax for more than 2
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                   loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.summary()
```

after running this code i am getting this error:

```
classifier.fit(training_set,
                  epochs = 5,
                  validation_data = test_set)
```

I have tried to run this code with 5 epoches and 20 epoches but this code is not running and throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because of not training with the exact same dense unit of the training files. Make them equal and try it again. Your error will then be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).